# @transactional annotated class wrapped with proxy, but transaction is not created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Well... Tried to find in google and here but failed. Here is my story:

- Spring MVC 3.1.1 RELEASE
- Spring Data JPA 1.1.0 RELEASE
- Hibernate 3.6.9.Final

Problem: I have method save(...) with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) annotation. But transaction is not being created.

Other findings:
1) When I annotate with @Transactional method from other service, transaction being created.

```
21:49:13.397 [DEBUG] (http-8080-2) org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  - Creating new transaction with name [com.xen.components.page.PageServiceImpl.findAllOrdered]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
```

2) Service where this method is located being wrapped with proxy(I saw in debug) and method being invoked from controller, so the call goes through proxy. 
3) Both services in root application context. Output of log.error(context):

```
OrderServiceImpl  - Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 17 21:48:30 FET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
PageServiceImpl  - Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 17 21:48:30 FET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

Here is the code of method:

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl extends CRUDServiceImpl<Order> implements OrderService {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OrderServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private OrderRepository repo;

@Autowired
private OrderItemService orderItemService;

@Override
protected CRUDRepository<Order> getRepository() {
    return repo;
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Order save(Order entity) {
    if (entity.getCreationDate() == null) {
        entity.setCreationDate(new Date());
    }

    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        increasePopularityForProductsInOrder(entity);
        // throws NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

        decreaseStockNumberForSkusInOrder(entity);
    }

    return super.save(entity);
}

private void increasePopularityForProductsInOrder(Order order) {
    List<OrderItem> items = order.getItems();

    for (OrderItem item : items) {
        orderItemService.increasePopularity(item);
    }
}

private void decreaseStockNumberForSkusInOrder(Order order) {
    List<OrderItem> items = order.getItems();

    for (OrderItem item : items) {
        orderItemService.removeFromStock(item);
    }
}
}
```

This method being invoked from controller. Controller code is straightforward, only validation and orderService.save(...) call.
Here is my config:

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xen">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xen" />

</beans>
```

servletContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xen" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.xen.common.util.PagePopulationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="error">
    <property name="warnLogCategory" value="stdout" />
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">404</prop>
            <prop key=".NotFoundException">404</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
  </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
          <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
          </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence>
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Update:
CartController.java

```
@Controller
public class CartController {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CartController.class);

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/submit-order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam long deliveryType, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
        Order order = CartHelper.getOrderFromRequest(request);
        uiModel.addAttribute("email", email);

        // 1. check if address is set
        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(order.getClientInfo().getFirstName())) {
            MessageBean.createErrorMessage("cart.enter-address.error").displayMessage(uiModel);
            populateForm(uiModel, order);
            return "cart";
        }

        // 2. check if specified deliveryType exist
        DeliveryType type = null;
        try {
            type = deliveryTypeService.findOne(deliveryType);
        } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
            MessageBean.createErrorMessage("cart.invalid-delivery-type.error").displayMessage(uiModel);
            populateForm(uiModel, order);
            return "cart";
        }
        order.setDeliveryType(type);

        // 3. check if email is valid
        if (!StringUtil.isEmailValid(email)) {
            MessageBean.createErrorMessage("cart.invalid-email.error").displayMessage(uiModel);
            populateForm(uiModel, order);
            return "cart";
        }
        order.getClientInfo().setEmail(email);

        // 4. check if order is not empty
        if (order.isEmpty()) { // should not be possible
            log.warn("Empty order submission registered! " + order);
            return "cart/empty";
        }

        order = orderService.save(order);
        CartHelper.updateOrderForRequest(request, order);

        // 5. send notification to client
        try {
            sendNotificationToClient(order, request);
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(MessageBean.MESSAGE_BEAN_KEY, MessageBean.createSuccessMessage("cart.order.successfuly.created"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(MessageBean.MESSAGE_BEAN_KEY, MessageBean.createErrorMessage("cart.failed.to.send.notification.during.order.saving"));
        }

        return "redirect:/orders/success";
    }

...

}
```

If you have any thoughts, please, post it. I'm getting crazy about this.

Comment: can you post the controller code?

Comment: With EJB,some special rules applies when the @TransactionAttribute annotation is used with an overrided method. To be honest I don´t know if this also can apply to Spring, but just in case try to rename the method.

Comment: drorb, thank you for reply. I've added only controller method that invoke service, because controller is pretty big.

Comment: Gabriel, thanks. Unfortunately it does't help.

Comment: Try to use JDK proxy instead of CGLIB, setting proxy-target-class to false on tx:annotation-driven

Comment: @Gabriel Aramburu: There is no special rule for `@Transactional` annotation when using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your transaction manger when initializing annotations, so update your config file to be like:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ean, thanks for try. But doesn't work. `"transactionManager"` is default value for this attribute.